# how to solve configurable product image adapter error in magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, image, gd2

I'm getting error in magento2.2.6 on frontend  for configuration type product

> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Image adapter for 'SLGD2NEW' is not setup.
>
> also command not working bin/magento catalog:images:resize same error throwing

I'm surprised that error not got for simple product type on frontend

Comment: Is that an attribute "SLGD2NEW"?

Comment: its not attribute. i have setup default magento with sample data

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below PHP extensions? if not installed then please intalled it.:

```
 gd2, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both
```

For Linux, you can install GD using below commands :

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: GD  lib Support - enabled and also imagick enabled